# show and hide google sheets separately for specific user

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a google spreadsheet for my team members where they can save their logs so I have made a separate sheet for each of them but I do not want to let them see each others logs due to some privacy reasons.

I am hiding sheets with the app script and associated them with the email address of the users. But  when any user opens his/her sheet then it works just fine, but if other users open their sheets then it get messed up.

If user A open A1 rest other sheets are hidden, but when user B opens B1 then it gets rendered to user A also. I can't understand if its because the google spreadsheet has only one instance or its some fault in my code.

Answer (score 2):

### Unfortunately your approach is not feasible

As you suspected, the google spreadsheet has only one instance.

So if one user performs any change on the visibility of a sheet, this change will be also visible to all other users that work on the same spreadsheet.

As a workaround, you can create a separate spreadsheet for each user that cannot be accessed by other users.

Those spreadsheets can be synced to a common master spreadsheet that can be seen and edited by you.

You can do this sync with a simple `=IMPORTRANGE()` formula.

Comment: That is what I actually did not want to do. Well if it's true the sheet has one instance then it's a dead-end. Thank you though.